# Hearing loss -- need RPi Zeros to listen to bells, buzzers, or chimes and send some notification

Tags: audio, server

I can't hear

- my doorbell when I'm in my shop
- the dryer's mechanical chime when I'm upstairs
- the oven's little buzzer when I'm out of the kitchen
- which smoke alarm is going off (hearing aids don't have much sense of direction.)

How can an RPi Zero listen for a certain sound or frequency, and then trigger some remote notification? By WiFi? SMS? Other RPis with flashing lights and text displays?

I want to put one near every audio alarm in the house, to act as a relay.

Comment: It might be easier to tie into the existing doorbell switch as a microphone would need to differntate between sounds in a potentially noisey environment. Likewise you could use a motion sensor to detect the dryer cycle ending.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's not a wired doorbell, and I couldn't find one that offered multiple ringers for one switch. Plus, range is a problem, and they're all coded so we don't ring each other's doorbells.

It seemed to me that a general solution might be in order -- all those different alarms and most of them are pretty useless when earshot is only about 10 yards!

Comment: You could use the door bell or chime itself to signal the Pi.

Comment: If you can wire directly to the appliances you might check the ESP8266 instead of the PiZero, it's even cheaper (and sells in quantities larger than one). If OTOH you need to discriminate specific sound I guess the ESP is not the first choice.

Comment: I have one of those cheap wireless door bells.  Presuming you don't know much about electronics or programming, I think it would still be easier (and more foolproof) to open the receiver/chime up and wire it to something (including a pi) directly rather than trying to detect the sound.  This actually has some advantages over a hardwired bell: 1) No chance of dangerous voltages involved, 2) Cheap and easy to replace if you screw it  up.  I.e., it is as close to a "risk free" experiment/pet project as you are likely to find.

Comment: Contra @Ghanima I think while the ESP8266 is generally cheaper (but nb., you will probably need a $15-20 version for this, not the $5-10 ones), it is also going to be significantly harder to work with for people without much programming experience.

Comment: And maybe contra @SteveRobillard I think trying to catch the radio signal used by the ringer is going to be the hardest (but also "most elegant") solution.

Comment: While I hope that Ron got his *Moderator Overflow* hat, I withdraw my previous comment and suggest we keep the chat to where it belongs ;)

Comment: This is my very first foray into the raspberry pi stackexchange. I didn't know there were hats!

Seriously, I was thinking about **all** of us hearing impaired folks. We could sure use a general, not-too-wizardly solution for all those alarms we can't hear: mechanical, electrical, or electronic!

Comment: For the mechanical noise-makers I'd be tempted to look into using piezo sensors. You *should* be able to stick a sensor to the bells or cases and identify an approximate pattern or amplitude closely enough to distinguish between background noise and an alert.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use noise/sound sensors like this one from sparkfun: [SparkFun Sound Detector](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12642) (just an example)

They provide analog and/or digital outputs to trigger some kind of visual notification with the pi zeros.

I don't know if they are suitable for all your applications, but things like the door bell should work provided you set the correct threshold.

Comment: Thank you -- that is certainly an option in low-noise situations!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make the computers listen for specific sounds, pick them out from ambient noise, and recognize them, you are probably in for quite a task.

I would recommend to start looking at [audacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_(audio_editor)) and [nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_(programming_language)) and go from there.

Once you have done that, you could just add light beacons to the Pis and have them flash in unison on detection. The easiest way to do that would probably be to have one of them acting like a server, and the other ones as slaves. You could hook this up via a web server.

Comment: I'm curious: how would starting looking at Audacity and Nyquist help OP to process real-time audio on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I knew the RPi could do voice recognition, and I just assumed frequency recognition would be easier. Not so, huh?

Comment: I like the idea of having the Pis flash in unison!

Comment: Those got me started. Now I'm looking at RPi guitar tuners or frequency detectors. 

I looked at [Audio Fingerprinting](http://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python/), but maybe that is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn Python , especially NumPy. Look at this example project utilizing those techniques :

https://github.com/benjaminchodroff/alarmBeepDetect

Comment: Working on it! It's been about 8 years, but it is coming back. Thank you.